# Array sum of numeric element of alphanumeric values

Tags: excel

I have a series of alphanumeric data in 'A' column:

[image: image of data]

I want the sum of the numeric values in cell "B1" for all ending with `k` and a sum of all ending with `p` in cell "C1".

I mean adding all the numeric element of the values.

Answer (score 0):

Apply Text to Columns to ColumnB with fixed width and the split after the first character.
in C1 enter `=A1&B1` and copy down to suit.
in D1: `=SUMIF(B:B,"k",A:A)`
in E1: `=SUMIF(B:B,"p",A:A)`
Select ColumnsC:E, copy, Paste Special…, Values over the top.
Delete ColumnsA:B.

Comment: thanks it did work, but is there a way to do it without splitting and in just in one cell directly, because i dont have the luxury of adding a column

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps with an array **formula****:

=SUM(IF(RIGHT(A1:A100)="k",0+SUBSTITUTE(A1:A100,"k","")))

Change the range (A1:A100) to a suitably larger one if required - though not TOO large (and certainly don't use A:A!) since, unlike e.g. SUMIF(S), array formulas calculate over all cells within the range, whether beyond your last non-empty cell or not.

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*